# Are portal keys sharable across factions in Ingress?

Tags: ingress

As the title says, are portal keys sharable across factions (through dropping) in Ingress?

In other words, if a member of the opposing faction drops a key on the ground, can I see it and pick it up?

Comment: The answer for this very likely also covers all dropped items.

Comment: @Daenyth Probably you are right. I will update the question itself, if the answer appears to be generic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can pick dropped items from the enemy faction.

Here is a Resistant player seeing Enlightened items
[image: A Resistant player seeing Enlightened items]

source : [reddit.com/r/ingress : ProTip: Don't drop your loot at your house if you live near the road.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/146eb9/protip_dont_drop_your_loot_at_your_house_if_you/)