# Are dropped items accessible to the other faction?

Tags: ingress

I have a few items I would like to make available to my faction. The only drop points where my paths cross with other faction members are highly public transport hubs in my city.

Is it safe to drop items in public or will they be available to members of the other faction that happen to go through the area as well? Should we use secure messaging to coordinate drops at an off-beat location or are drops only visible to our faction anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are portal keys sharable across factions in Ingress?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95186/are-portal-keys-sharable-across-factions-in-ingress)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are publicly accessible.